# new lines are not getting eliminated

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to replace newline etc kind of values using regexp_replace. But when I open the result in query result window, I can still see the new lines in the text. Even when I copy the result, I can see new line characters. See output for example, I just copied from the result.

Below is my query

```
select regexp_replace('abc123     

/n
CHAR(10)

头疼,'||CHR(10)||'allo','[^[:alpha:][:digit:][ \t]]','') from dual;
```

/ I just kept for testing characters.

Output:

```
abc123     

/n
CHAR(10)

头疼,
allo
```

How to remove the new lines from the text?

Expected output:

```
abc123     /nCHAR(10)头疼,allo
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two mistakes in your code. One of them causes the issue you noticed.

First, in a bracket expression, in Oracle regular expressions (which follow the POSIX standard), there are no escape sequences. You probably meant `\t` as escape sequence for tab - within the bracket expression. (Note also that in Oracle regular expressions, there are no escape sequences like `\t` and `\n` anyway. If you must preserve tabs, it can be done, but not like that.)

Second, regardless of this, you include two character classes, `[:alpha:]` and `[:digit:]`, and also `[ \t]` in the (negated) bracket expression. The last one is not a character class, so the `[` as well as the space, the backslash and the letter t are interpreted as literal characters - they stand in for themselves. The closing bracket, on the other hand, has special meaning. The **first** of your two closing brackets is interpreted as the end of the bracket expression; and the **second** closing bracket is interpreted as being an additional, literal character that must be matched! Since there is no such literal closing bracket anywhere in the string, nothing is replaced.

To fix both mistakes, replace `[ \t]` with the `[:blank:]` character class, which consists exactly of space and tab. (And, note that `[:alpha:][:digit:]` can be written more compactly as `[:alnum:]`.)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I read in another question and thought it would work for oracle as well. Besides the POSIX standard, do we have a literal match of tab character in oracle?

Comment: @user14999956 - There are two other ways. One is to simply type a tab where you need it; that works, but the problem is that someone else reading the code won't know what is there. In addition, some idiotic IDE's, like my SQL Developer, may convert tab to several spaces as you type, so you won't actually have a tab in the code, you will have several spaces; definitely not good. The other, safer way is to write the character number - you interrupt the quoted string, concatenate `chr(9)`, and concatenate the rest of the string - similar to what you did in the input with `chr(10)`.

Comment: @thatjeffsmith - To be more specific, what I don't understand (and I don't think is smart) is, regardless of the settings you mentioned, and of which I am aware, why does the IDE replace tabs with spaces *in string literals*, enclosed in single-quotes? It makes prefect sense to be able to replace tabs with spaces in *code*, but not in *data* - regardless of those settings. Is that something that the developers of my IDE could consider? Thanks!

Comment: Can you ask a new question and share a test case? That screams bug and I'd be upset too @mathguy

Comment: @thatjeffsmith - OK, I'll do that on the OTN platform (or whatever they call it now), I think that's a better forum for this. A bit later today when I get a chance. Thanks!

Comment: cool, thanks @mathguy - i know it takes energy/caring to spend the time to share this stuff, but we do want to fix things, so it's appreciated

Comment: @mathguy your idea makes sense, but is there *any* editor that can change the way it handles tab characters depending on whether the cursor is within a quoted string?

Comment: @WilliamRobertson - not sure. I'll try in `vi` when I get a chance. But here's my reasoning: while I type in the SQL Dev editor, I have the option (if I turn that on) to have auto-completion. I believe that would not be active while I am typing in a string (I can test that too). So the editor does have a way of "knowing" when it is in a string, vs. outside. I don't see why that flag couldn't be used to switch the behavior of converting tab to spaces. Lots of speculations on my part, but at least that's the thought process.